# Extract value from object if in object - reference error

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I want to construct an object using another object as an argument map. Arguments are not mandatory.

Why can't i do the following :

```
var Key = function( args ) {
    text in args && this.text = args.text;
};
```

to initialize my members in a single line ? Must i really do if() ... ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The full error message is `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`, which explains why it was not working and why your answer fixes it.

Comment: Why not just use `if()`? It'll end up being the same number of characters as your solution, and it'll read more clearly. `if (text in args) this.text = args.text`

Comment: I always add brackets when i use a if to keep my code uniform so that would take three lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FOperator_Precedence) that doesn't align with the desired meaning.

The highest precedence within that expression statement is the `.` operator. Because it has the highest precedence of any operator, I won't bother to use parens.

---

The next highest precedence is the `in` operator, so we can wrap it with its operands first.

```
(text in args) && this.text = args.text;
```

---

After that the `&&` operator has the next highest precedence, so again we can wrap it with its operands.

```
((text in args) && this.text) = args.text;
```

---

And so now we can see the issue. We are attempting to assign the `args.text` to the result of the `((text in args) && this.text)` expression, which is invalid because it's not an assignment to a resolvable identifier.

Because we now see that we need to manually enforce the precedence of the `=` operator, we can wrap it with the operands on which we expect it to operate, and adjust the parens for `&&`.

```
((text in args) && (this.text = args.text));
```

---

And because we know that the rest of the precedence naturally worked out fine for our intention, we can get rid of the other parens.

```
text in args && (this.text = args.text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explaination. I thought that this last line i found was right but i'm getting an error : "text is undefined". Should i use text as a string instead : 'text' in args ?

Comment: @Virus721: If you don't have a `text` variable, and you are actually intending to look for a property named `"text"` within the `args` object, then yes, you'd need a string.

Comment: @Crasy Train I've tried : `if('text' in args) this.text = args.text;` but it says : `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand args`. I thought i had do that kind of things many times before, never had these weird problems.

Comment: @Virus721: Then perhaps `args` is `undefined`. A quick fix would be `if ("text" in (args || {}))` This way you'll get `false`, which is what I'd think you'd want if nothing was passed.